# Сохранение и чтение из хранилища сессий

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не могу понять, где и в чём ошибка. Хочу сохранить [в сессию страницы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) нажатые кнопки фильтров, чтобы после перезагрузки страницы и т.п. восстановить выбор пользователя.

- Каждая кнопка имеет уникальный атрибут `id`;
- Кнопка нажата, если есть `.btn-warning`.

Как организована логика

- При загрузке страницы получаю из сессионного хранилища `id` нажатых ранее кнопок;
- Если такие есть, то добавляю к каждой `.btn-warning` и перезапускаю фильтрацию;
- При нажатии на любую кнопку фильтра получаю список всех нажатых кнопок и заношу его в сессионное хранилище (ниже кода этой функции нет, т.к. только будет путь и засорять).

Ниже код

```
const CHECKED_FILTER_CLASS='btn-warning'; //имя класса, наличие которого у кнопки определяет нажата она или нет / нужно её учитывать или нет
const SESSION_STORAGE_ACTIVE_FILTERS_NAME='active_filters'; //имя ключа в сессионном хранилище js с json массивом нажатых кнопок фильтров


let active_filters=load_from_session(SESSION_STORAGE_ACTIVE_FILTERS_NAME); //Получаем данные из сессии страницы о нажатых кнопках

//Если есть данные, то восстанавливаем кнопки и перезапускаем фильтр.
if ((active_filters && active_filters.length>0){
    restore_pushed_filter_buttons(active_filters);
    //apply_filter();
}

/**
 * Делает указанные кнопки нажатыми
 *
 * @param buttons - массив с id кнопок
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function restore_pushed_filter_buttons(buttons) {
    for (i = buttons.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        jQuery('#'+buttons[i]).addClass(CHECKED_FILTER_CLASS);
    }

    return true;
}

/**
 * Сохраняет переданные данные в сессию вкладки
 *
 * @param key - имя ключа, под которым данные будут сохранены в сессии
 * @param data - данные, которые будут сохранены в сессии
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function save_in_session(key, data) {
    if (Array.isArray(data)){
        data=JSON.stringify(data);
    }
    sessionStorage.setItem(key, data);

    return true;
}

/**
 * Получает из сессии вкладки данные по ключу
 *
 * @param key - имя ключа в сесси
 * @return {boolean}
 */
function load_from_session(key) {
    let data=sessionStorage.getItem(key);
    if (data) {
        return JSON.parse(data);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Проблема следующая - данные в сессии НЕ сохраняются, если перейти на любую другую страницу. НО если закомментировать весь код в функции `load_from_session()`, то данные сохраняются (если смотреть в инструментах разработчика google chrome -> Application - > Session store) при переходах по сайту.

Я проверяю существование данных в сессии путём их загрузки оттуда с помощью функции `load_from_session()` каждый раз при инициализации js. Не понятно только, почему данные после считыванию удаляются... Пробовал сразу же после считывания записать эти данные обратно:

```
function load_from_session(key) {
    let data=sessionStorage.getItem(key);
    save_in_session(SESSION_STORAGE_ACTIVE_FILTERS_NAME, data); //костыль, который не работает.
    if (data) {
        return JSON.parse(data);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Но ничего всё равно не работает. Чёрт знает что. Если поможет делу, то вот ссылка на девелоп - https://krol.of.by/catalog

Comment: да вроде все верно... а с локалстореджем такая же штука?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ошибка в логике, в функции `get_active_filters`, которая в вашем вопросе не представлена)

При переходе на любую страницу(не каталог), функция `get_active_filters` выполняется при загрузке страницы и ищет выбранные фильтры. Поскольку фильтров нету(поскольку на страницы нет фильтрации), то она считает, что не один фильтр не выбран и записывает(вызывает функцию `save_in_session`) пустое значение с фильтрами в `sessionStorage`.

Думаю, вам надо как-то определять при загрузке страницы, есть ли вообще блок с фильтрами на странице.

Посмотрите на строчки  //**---------------------------------------------------------------**//

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) { //ОЖИДАНИЕ DOM


      // const BUTTON_DATA_FILTER_VALUE_NAME='class'; //имя атрибута data у кнопки фильтров в котором содержится имя-класс текущего фильтра
      const FILTER_GROUP_MULTIPLE = 'type'; //имя класса тех групп фильтров, которые учитываться должны комплексно. Например ТИП. У каждого кролика может быть несколько типов. И при фильтрации нужно это учитывать
      const CHECKED_FILTER_CLASS = 'btn-warning'; //имя класса, наличие которого у кнопки определяет нажата она или нет / нужно её учитывать или нет
      const SESSION_STORAGE_ACTIVE_FILTERS_NAME = 'active_filters'; //имя ключа в сессионном хранилище js с json массивом нажатых кнопок фильтров



      let active_filters = load_from_session(SESSION_STORAGE_ACTIVE_FILTERS_NAME); //Получаем данные из сессии страницы о нажатых кнопках
      //Если есть данные, то восстанавливаем кнопки и перезапускаем фильтр.
      if (active_filters && active_filters.length > 0) {
        restore_pushed_filter_buttons(active_filters);
        //**---------------------------------------------------------------**//
        apply_filter(); // ВЫЗОВ ПРИ ЗАГРУЗКЕ
      }

      /**
       * Делает указанные кнопки нажатыми
       *
       * @param buttons - массив с id кнопок
       * @returns {boolean}
       */
      function restore_pushed_filter_buttons(buttons) {
        for (i = buttons.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          jQuery('#' + buttons[i]).addClass(CHECKED_FILTER_CLASS);
        }

        return true;
      }

      /**
       * Сохраняет переданные данные в сессию вкладки
       *
       * @param key - имя ключа, под которым данные будут сохранены в сессии
       * @param data - данные, которые будут сохранены в сессии
       * @returns {boolean}
       */
      function save_in_session(key, data) {
        if (Array.isArray(data)) {
          data = JSON.stringify(data);
        }
        sessionStorage.setItem(key, data);

        return true;
      }

      /**
       * Получает из сессии вкладки данные по ключу
       *
       * @param key - имя ключа в сесси
       * @return {boolean}
       */
      function load_from_session(key) {
        let data = sessionStorage.getItem(key);
        // save_in_session(SESSION_STORAGE_ACTIVE_FILTERS_NAME, data); //костыль, который не работает.
        if (data) {
          return JSON.parse(data);
        }

        return false;
      }





      rabbit_resizer();



      jQuery('.filter-btn').click(function() {
        if (is_filter_button_pushed($(this))) {
          $(this).removeClass(CHECKED_FILTER_CLASS);
        } else {
          $(this).addClass(CHECKED_FILTER_CLASS);
        }

        // console.log(get_active_filters());
        // console.log(get_unactive_filters());
        // console.log(get_unactive_filters());
        apply_filter();
      });

      function apply_filter() {
        hide_all_rabbits();
         //**---------------------------------------------------------------**//
        show_filters_rabbits(get_active_filters(), get_unactive_filters());// УСТАНОВКА ФИЛЬТРОВ
      }


      function is_filter_button_pushed(ob) {
        if (ob.hasClass(CHECKED_FILTER_CLASS)) {
          return true;
        }

        return false;
      }



      function get_active_filters() {
        let selected_filters = [];
        jQuery(".filter-btn").each(function() {
          if ($(this).hasClass(CHECKED_FILTER_CLASS)) {
            selected_filters.push($(this).attr('id'))
          }
        });
        //**---------------------------------------------------------------**//
        save_in_session('active_filters', selected_filters);// ПЕРЕЗАПИСЫВАНИ sessionStorage ФИЛЬТРОВ

        return selected_filters;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Я добавил сейчас к функции `get_active_filters()` `alert('!!!')` в самое её начало. Однако при переходе на страницы другие и т.п. alert не срабатывает. Только при нажатии на кнопку фильтров появляется сообщение. Функция эта у меня нигде сама по себе не вызывается. Где вы увидели её вызов при загрузке страницы?

Comment: Функцию `get_active_filters`  вызыват функция `apply_filter`, которая в свою очередь вызвается при `jQuery(document).ready`. И не ставьте алерт. Лучше напишите `debugger`  и откройте консоль разработичка в хроме.

Comment: Да, разобрался. Вызвал `console.trace();` Спасибо огромное!